C# Best way to break out of multiple nested functions with high performance
*Sorry, I will continuously edit my article to make my description clearer to express my question.
This may also cause some inconvenience.
I have an automation program used to control other applications(like Browser or DesktopApp).
I've created a function with a "while" to determine the current page or state of the application, deciding the next action to execute.
void OuterMostFunc()
{
    while(!exit)
    {
        InquiryLatestOuterAppInfo();
        if(<NeedPerform>)
        {
            //InitSomethings...
            DirectingFunc();
            //HandleSomethings...
        }
        Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);
    }
}

void DirectingFunc()
{
    if(A_Page_Cond)
        A_Page_Func();
    else if(B_Page_Cond)
        B_Page_Func();
    ...
}

However, at the same time, these applications may be manually operated or encounter unexpected events to change page or state.
Therefore, I must check for changes in status at many key points and break out to return to the outermost function to reassess the situation.
A relatively elegant solution is to utilize Try-Catch, along with customizing a BreakException, allowing me to return to the outermost function from anywhere in the code.
Additionally, I reset all critical variables at the outermost level, so I don't need to worry about issues caused by interruptions.
void OuterMostFunc()
{
    while(!exit)
    {
        InquiryLatestOuterAppInfo();
        if(<NeedPerform>)
        {
            //InitSomethings...
            try
            {
                DirectingFunc();
            }
            catch(BreakExcetion ex)
            {}
            //HandleSomethings...
        }
        Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);
    }
}

void Any_Deep_Level_Func()
{
    //DoSomethings.
    if(CheckPageIsChanged())
        throw new BreakException();
    //DoSomethings.
}

For a long time, this approach has been useful and reliable.
However, due to the program's application context demanding utmost speed, the performance overhead brought by Try-Catch becomes difficult to ignore.
For example, Try-Catch requires tens of milliseconds of execution time and imposes a relatively significant CPU burden."
If every function were to return bool (or out bool), and then we checked whether to return or execute the next step after calling each function, it would indeed allow us to quickly return to the outermost function.
However, this approach seems to pose a disaster for the readability of the code, especially considering the actual complexity and multilayered nature of the functions called in the program.
Supplementary Note:

For example, I might need to perform a series of operation steps on Page A, but before executing certain critical steps, I'll need to check the somethings again to see if there have been any changes.
My program creates multiple threads, each of which executes the OuterMostFunc for individual applications
In this process, the program needs to poll other applications to obtain the latest status, and cannot rely on other applications to actively notify changes in status. (Other applications are not part of my project.)
The priority is the speed at which the program executes corresponding operations after state changes, with performance being secondary.

Note:
The process requires the inner functions to check for state changes and decide whether to cancel, rather than having the outer layer check and call cancel.
This is because it involves operations on other applications, and issuing instructions from the outer layer while the inner function is executing could cause conflicts.
Is this layered checking approach considered cleaner?
Pass the CancellationTokenSource variable to all non-unit operations functions, and check it after calling.
(Assuming we're not discussing asynchronous and while loop issues for now.)
void OuterMostFunc()
{
    while (!exit)
    {
        InquiryLatestOuterAppInfo();
        if(<NeedPerform>)
        {
            //InitSomethings...
            CancellationTokenSource cts = new 
            CancellationTokenSource();
            DirectingFunc(cts);
            //HandleSomethings...
        }
    }
}

void DirectingFunc(CancellationTokenSource cts)
{
    if(A_Page_Cond)
        A_Page_Func(cts);
    else if(B_Page_Cond)
        B_Page_Func(cts);
}

void A_Page_Func(CancellationTokenSource cts)
{
    //DoSomethings.
    XX_Func(cts);
    if (cts.IsCancellationRequested)
        return;
    //DoSomethings.
}

void XX_Func(CancellationTokenSource cts)
{
    //DoSomethings.
    YY_Func(cts);
    if (cts.IsCancellationRequested)
        return;
    //DoSomethings.
}

void YY_Func(CancellationTokenSource cts)
{
    //DoSomethings.
    if (CheckPageIsChanged())
    {
        cts.Cancel();
        return;
    }
    //DoSomethings.
}


@marsze
Thanks!
The thread will sleep for a few milliseconds after each execution of InnerFunc.
The performance overhead caused by the while loop in this program might be necessary because the automation program needs to constantly check the status of other applications and perform actions (such as clicking buttons or executing scripts) at the fastest speed (in milliseconds) possible, repeating this process after each action.
Therefore, the performance impact of Try-Catch becomes relatively hard to ignore.

Thread.Sleep will still lock up the current thread, you shouldn't use that. Switch to an async model, which will actually free the thread.

Of course no one says that you shouldn't use try catch blocks for performance reasons.  They are for exceptional behaviour.
The issue that you have (given you have a reason to run synchronously, if not you have a different issue, see answer) is: You shouldn't throw them for other situations, i.e. to control yourr program.
If your readability degrades you might want to think of using a CancellationToken  (or something that comes close to this) in a scope where you dont need to pass it around, statically or whatever. However, that loop as a whole seems weird to me.

Thank you, I need some time to think about and implement testing for these suggestion.

As others said, you should NEVER, EVER use exceptions to control the logical flow of your application. Its a BIG, HUGE code smell and a red flag. Get rid of this design please.

Thread.Sleep is a code smell. If something changes or nothing changes while the thread is sleeping, you can't adjust until the sleep completes. Spinning on Sleep means the thread repeatedly sleeps and wakes until something changes at which point the thread has invariably "over slept". Sometimes Sleep is the least worst option but, when possible, it's better to have the thread "actively" wait or block until the very moment it is needed.

@JonathanDodds Thanks. In this process, the program needs to poll other applications to obtain the latest status, and cannot rely on other applications to actively notify changes in status. (Other applications are not part of my project.) Therefore, even if I use a Wait method here to wait for events, I still need to send commands to poll the status of other applications at continuously. Is there a more efficient way to handle this than while and sleep, such as using a Timer?

I don't know what "latest status" means for your program and I don't know what "send commands" to other applications means for your program. You can wait on a Process to exit and you can read a stream and/or handle IPC asynchronously but I don't know if "status" is about any of that.

If you are performing multiple wait for state1; do action1; wait for state2; do action2; then you might want to write each sequence of actions as a co-routine. You could build a framework around yield return similar to unity's (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html). Or you could build some equivalent around async / await.

Since this runs synchronously, having a while loop that runs continuously will itself be detrimental for performance, especially when using Thread.Sleep calls. Don't do that. Switch to an asynchronous implementation.
Here is how a long-running application (such as a windows service or web service) is commonly implemented in recent .NET versions using BackgroundService:
public sealed class AppService : BackgroundService
{
    // change the update interval as you like, or read from config
    private static readonly _interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(20);
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

    public AppService(ILogger<Worker> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            try
            {
                // use asynchronous check if possible
                // (synchronous might also be fine here)
                if (await CheckChangedAsync(stoppingToken))
                {
                    // do something
                }
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException) when (stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                // was canceled
                break;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                 _logger.LogError(exception, "Unexpected exception occured");
                 // throw or exit gracefully
                 throw;
            }
            // pause to free resources before the next update
            await Task.Delay(_interval, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}

Note:

Thread.Sleep will still use up a thread, so the async approach is better
Async itself is very fast, fast enough for whatever you are possibly doing here
If you need to make the checks often, and you are able to actually perform them asynchronously, you could also get rid of the _interval altogether, and just rely on the asynchronous nature of CheckChangedAsync

